# Word for '100% majority'?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word for majority wherein someone or something gets all the votes cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**unanimity**
juːnəˈnɪmɪti/
noun
agreement by all people involved; **consensus**.

(definition from Google)

Answer (score 5):

I think that would be "unanimous".

Comment: Is that the only word to serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

*Unanimity* is where everyone involved votes for a candidate or proposal. All are of one mind.

There may be a situation where all votes **cast** are for a proposal, but not everyone votes. Thus there are no votes against the proposal. This is usually indicated by *nem con,* for *nemo contra,* "no-one against".